# make jQuery scrollTop Not to leave browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm looking for a solution that will make scrollTop not to leave records in browser history.

When i first launch the page I wanted browser to go to a specific section of it if url has a parameter with an internal anchor name. so i do this:

```
$('html,body').animate(
{
    scrollTop: $(".section[tagname='"+url_tagname+"']").offset().top
},
'slow');
```

But now when i hit browser "back" button it goes to the page top first. SO i actually have to hit "back" twice to go to previous page.

Is there a way to make scrolltop not to leave navigation history?

Comment: `scrolltop` doesn't push entry in browser's history. Your issue surely comes from somewhere else or i don't understand your issue. Maybe you could provide online link where this behaviour can be checked

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Are you clicking on an anchor with `href="#` or similar? Is it onload / onhashchange?

Comment: I figured out where my problem was, scrolltop did not put anything to history, however when i was trying to change url(remove section number) i did:
window.location.hash = "";
this actually added a step to browser history. I still need url to be cleaned up after scrolltop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the page to save the #anchor link when clicked on the same page correct?

Use a listener, and prevent default link action.

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will save you having multiples of the same page in history, but you'll still have the #anchor tag in the URL if navigated from another page.

Edit: Actual answer was provided by myself in comments: "You want to rewrite the URL? Your question was more towards anchor tags. If you want to change the url use: window.history.replaceState(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history"

Comment: I want anchor to be removed from the link(location.hash) without leaving a step in history. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to rewrite the URL? Your question was more towards anchor tags. If you want to change the url use: window.history.replaceState(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history